# SqlClient not cancelling SqlDataReader when CancellationTokenSource.Cancel in vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, sqlclient

I'm downloading a file using SQL Server in a query. I have a CLR function that takes a file on the server, converts it to binary, and returns it to the client as a binary.

This works fine, and I'm properly streaming the binary to a local (client) file in small batches (Sub CopyStream).

I want to be able to cancel the query at anytime on user request.

The below console program will automatically call the `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` method, which I can properly catch and use the `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method to throw the exception.

The local file stops getting written to, but the reader keeps reading until the file is done, of a timeout occurs.

How can I cancel the reader mid-stream?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Public running As Boolean = False

    Public Sub CopyStream(ByVal input As Stream, ByVal output As Stream, ByRef i As Integer, cancellationtokensource As CancellationTokenSource)
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(128) {}
        Dim len As Integer = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        While (len > 0)
            output.Write(buffer, 0, len)
            len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            If i = 1000 Then    ' I manually call the Cancel() function
                cancellationtokensource.Cancel()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            i = i + 1
        End While
    End Sub
    Private Const connectionString As String = connectionstring
    Sub Main()

        running = True
        caller()

        While running = True
            'continue running
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("Done Program")
    End Sub
    Async Sub caller()
        Dim canceltokensource As New CancellationTokenSource
        E2EStreamAsync(canceltokensource)
    End Sub

    Public Async Function E2EStreamAsync(cancellationtokensource As CancellationTokenSource) As Task
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Using readConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Dim openReadConn As Task = readConn.OpenAsync(cancellationtokensource.Token)
            Await Task.WhenAll(openReadConn)
            Using readCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("blobreturningquery", readConn)
                readCmd.CommandTimeout = 99999
                Using reader As SqlDataReader = Await readCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, cancellationtokensource.Token)
                    While Await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationtokensource.Token)
                        Try
                            Using file As Stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\Temp\file.pptx")
                                CopyStream(reader.GetStream(0), file, i, cancellationtokensource)
                                cancellationtokensource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                            End Using
                        Catch e As Exception
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e)
                            Exit Function
                        End Try
                    End While

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        running = False
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: There's no need to write `CopyStream` yourself, assuming any version of .NET not from the dark ages (Framework 4.5 or later). There's both `CopyTo` and [`CopyToAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copytoasync?view=net-7.0) available on all `Stream` derived classes and the async version accepts a `CancellationToken`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I just took this code from an MS article to make the proof of concept. I'll try to update the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like I was doing something wrong and not cancelling the whole chain of async methods. Cleaning up my function and calling only the reader as async, it worked as expected.

```
    Public Async Function E2EStreamAsync(cancellationtokensource As CancellationTokenSource) As Task
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim readConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    readConn.Open()
    'Dim openReadConn As Task = readConn.OpenAsync(cancellationtokensource.Token)
    'Await Task.WhenAll(openReadConn)
    Dim readCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("clr_FileDownloadAttachment 11923", readConn)
    readCmd.CommandTimeout = 99999
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = Await readCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess, cancellationtokensource.Token)
        While Await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationtokensource.Token)
            Try
                Using file As Stream = System.IO.File.Create("c:\Temp\file.pptx")
                    CopyStream(reader.GetStream(0), file, i, cancellationtokensource)
                    cancellationtokensource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
                End Using
            Catch e As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e)
                Exit Function
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    running = False
End Function
```